# Is there a way to know cumulative bonus to a specific skill that comes from all worn items?

Tags: grim-dawn

You can check the Character Sheet's second tab's "Character" section for "all skills" bonuses, but **what about individual skills**?

Is there any way to check this (even involving changes to vanilla game through mods)?

This can get pretty important when the cumulative bonus happens to exceed the maximum level for some skill. Then you could respec the lost bonus, to some other one not wasting it. But first one has to know there is some overcap.

Comment: I've never yet had more than +10 to a skill from gear. Don't you see overcap in skill window? The easy way to check for overcap would be to remove single piece of gear what gives +1 and if you still see maximum +10 in skill window - then you are overcapped.

Comment: The workaround you propose works, but what if you have more than one `+all skills` items (and with such bonuses for your second mastery to boot)? . What if you can't remember which one is which one? It quickly gets annoyingly unmanagable. Also Skills window won't show the overcap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to learn it in the negative (subtract all item bonuses to see the base modifiers).

In order to do that you need [GD Build Calculator](https://forums.crateentertainment.com/t/grimtools-build-calculator/38040). It's a portable app (no need to install). Download it and then just load your `player.gdc` file, switch to skills and hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

*Note: what the tool names "available points" are only the points still left for you in a hypothetical game progress to earn and distribute (it's a build calculating tool so it treats the state that you load only as a starting point).*